# Why does my function give me wrong argument error (0 for 1), and (1 for 0 )

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created the function "generate_verse" in my randomgenerator.rb file to generate a record from another Model's database (in this case, Movie):

```
class Randomgenerator < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :title, :query

    def generate_verse
      table = Movie.where{self.query.include?(:rating) == true}
      verse = table[0]
      return verse
    end

end
```

And when I try to run it in the show view:

```
%h2 #{@randomgenerator.title}

%ul#details
  %li
    Verse:
    = @randomgenerator.generate_verse()
```

It tells me I am giving the function a wrong number of arguments (0 for 1). However, when I added the argument (1) to see what it would do, it said that I was again giving the function the wrong amount of arguments (1 for 0). What am I doing wrong here? Any advice for designing this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing any arguments to `where`, so I suspect that is the problem. You're only providing a block, which does not contribute to the argument count.

If you can provide the stacktrace, we'd have a better shot at identifying the issue.

Comment: I can provide the stacktrace, but it is very long. Should I just provide the first half?

Comment: For starters, you can stop at whatever line involves code you've written (as opposed to Ruby or Rails code)

Comment: I replaced the curly brackets with parentheses, and that that solved that problem. It looks like the where function isn't the best method for what I'm looking for, so I'm using select instead. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use `where` in proper way or try `squeel`.